# Risk of losing LAST_INSERT_ID() with transactions

Tags: mysql

When using transactions for the code below, is there any risk of the `LAST_INSERT_ID()` not belonging to the first insert? That is, is it possible for another insert action to take place, say from different user interactions like `INSERT INTO comments (comment) VALUES ('kthanksbuy');`, which would then give `LAST_INSERT_ID()` the comments ID instead of the user's ID?

```
BEGIN;
INSERT INTO users (username, password)
  VALUES('john', 'pass');
INSERT INTO profiles (userid, bio, homepage) 
  VALUES(LAST_INSERT_ID(),'I am a lumberjack, and I am ok!', 'http://www.stackoverflow.com');
COMMIT;
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`LAST_INSERT_ID()` - Value of the AUTOINCREMENT column for the last INSERT.

Or more broad: `LAST_INSERT_ID()` returns a BIGINT UNSIGNED (64-bit) value representing the first automatically generated value successfully inserted for an AUTO_INCREMENT column as a result of the most recently executed INSERT statement. It is from [official documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id).

And it is definitely not first insert...

Comment: oh, I meant the first insert of that example, or more accuratly the previous insert (most recent).